OR-Tools CP-SAT python example terminates after creating solver
I am new to Google OR-Tools and trying to start by running a basic example from OR-Tools example library found here
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/samples/cp_sat_example.py.
Every code example gets hung up on the same part after creating the solver.
When I run the code I am not getting an output from any of the examples, each time it gets hung up after creating the solver, then the script just seems to terminate. I have modified this CP-Stat model code example with some print statements for debugging but I still can't figure out why every example gets hung up on the same part.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# [START program]
"""Simple solve."""
# [START import]
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
# [END import]


def main() -> None:
    """Minimal CP-SAT example to showcase calling the solver."""
    print("Starting the solver...")  # Debug print statement

    try:
        # Creates the model.
        # [START model]
        print("Creating model...")
        model = cp_model.CpModel()
        print("Model created.")
        # [END model]

        # Creates the variables.
        # [START variables]
        print("Creating variables...")
        var_upper_bound = max(50, 45, 37)
        x = model.NewIntVar(0, var_upper_bound, "x")
        y = model.NewIntVar(0, var_upper_bound, "y")
        z = model.NewIntVar(0, var_upper_bound, "z")
        print(f"Variables created: x in [0, {var_upper_bound}], y in [0, {var_upper_bound}], z in [0, {var_upper_bound}]")
        # [END variables]

        # Creates the constraints.
        # [START constraints]
        print("Adding constraints...")
        model.Add(2 * x + 7 * y + 3 * z <= 50)
        model.Add(3 * x - 5 * y + 7 * z <= 45)
        model.Add(5 * x + 2 * y - 6 * z <= 37)
        print("Constraints added.")
        # [END constraints]

        # [START objective]
        print("Setting objective...")
        model.Maximize(2 * x + 2 * y + 3 * z)
        print("Objective set.")
        # [END objective]

        # Creates a solver and solves the model.
        # [START solve]
        print("Creating solver...")
        solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
        print("Solver created.")
        
        print("Solving model...")
        status = solver.Solve(model)
        print(f"Model solved with status: {status}")
        # [END solve]

        # [START print_solution]
        print("Checking solution...")
        if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
            print(f"Maximum of objective function: {solver.ObjectiveValue()}\n")
            print(f"x = {solver.Value(x)}")
            print(f"y = {solver.Value(y)}")
            print(f"z = {solver.Value(z)}")
        else:
            print("No solution found.")
        # [END print_solution]

        # Statistics.
        # [START statistics]
        print("Printing statistics...")
        print("\nStatistics")
        print(f"  status   : {solver.StatusName(status)}")
        print(f"  conflicts: {solver.NumConflicts()}")
        print(f"  branches : {solver.NumBranches()}")
        print(f"  wall time: {solver.WallTime()} s")
        print("Statistics printed.")
        # [END statistics]

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print("Solver finished.")  # Debug print statement
# [END program]


I am using python version 3.12.1 with VS Code. I have uninstalled and reinstalled OR-Tools and all dependent libraries multiple times. The output in the terminal appears as follows:
Starting the solver...
Creating model...
Model created.
Creating variables...
Variables created: x in [0, 50], y in [0, 50], z in [0, 50]
Adding constraints...
Constraints added.
Setting objective...
Objective set.
Creating solver...
Solver created.
Solving model...

The optimized solution should look something like:
Model solved with status: 4  # This status code should indicate OPTIMAL or FEASIBLE

Checking solution...
Maximum of objective function: 32.0  # Example value
x = 5.0  # Example value
y = 0.0  # Example value
z = 0.0  # Example value

Printing statistics...

Statistics
  status   : OPTIMAL  # Example status
  conflicts: 0
  branches : 0
  wall time: 0.001 s
Statistics printed.
Solver finished.

I believe there is an issue with solver itself but I'm not sure how to diagnose what it is, it may be something simple that I am overlooking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Are you using or-tools 9.10 on windows ?
If yes, check the known issues in the release notes: https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases
You may need to update the visual studio redistributable libraries

Could not get it to work on Windows even after updating Visual Studio 2019 and 2022. Works great on wsl with ubuntu though.

yes, it works for some users, and fails for others. I have no explanations.

Your code runs perfectly fine for me.  Optimal value is 35, but that is a side issue.
There is something amiss with your environment/VS code/install.  I would try this set of steps in order, without skipping.  ;)

Restart your computer to clear up any issues with the environment
get a terminal window and use python's venv library to make a simple virtual environment
activate the venv (see the dox...it's a 1-liner)
pip install ortools after the venv is activated
run your code in the active venv

You should not need to open VS Code for any of the above.  If that all works above (exactly what I did) then you can expand outward and figure out the issue.
